# Newton-Raphson Method Using Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, scientific-computing, polynomials, newtons-method

I developed the code below for finding the roots of the given polynomial. It works fine, but I need to adapt it to find all roots and not simply stop when it converges. How do I go about doing this? I thought about creating an outer do loop for values of x, but I'm uncertain whether this is the right approach. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
PROGRAM nr
integer :: i
real :: x, f, df
write(*,*) "x=?"
read (*,*)  x           
write (*,*) '# Initial value: x=',x

 do i=1,100
     f= x**4 - 26*(x**3) + 131*(x**2) - 226*x + 120
     df = 4*(x**3) - 3.0*26*(x**2) + 2.0*131*x - 226
     write (*,*) i,x,f,df
     x = x-f/df
 end do

 write (*,*) '#x = ',x




END PROGRAM
```

Comment: Newton–Raphson will not do that for you, it is about finding a root, and that is all. In the general case you need something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method, or for the particular case of polynomials, you can check its related suggestions, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budan%27s_theorem and especially their combination, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-root_isolation

Comment: For the methods themselves, you may want to seek ideas/help on https://math.stackexchange.com/, so far this is not really about Fortran or programming, but mathematics.

Comment: I beg to differ, I think it's possible to devise a way to store the root given a criterion for convergence, an error variable perhaps, and then reapply the algorithm this time for a different starting x. It would do this till all roots are found, the loop will stop when the number of roots is the degree of the polynomial. I'm just not sure how to go about building this in fortran.

Comment: Yes, that is what the suggested algorithms address. Just they are not called "Newton-Raphson".

Comment: The thing is, I need to use Newton-Raphson. The question in my homework asked specifically to use this method to find **all** the roots. Again, I thank you for your suggestions, but I'd rather wait for someone else's support.

Comment: You can combine tags with `+`, so you can try searches like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newton-raphson+roots or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials+roots, or even all three of them, other tags, etc.

Comment: If it specifically roots of this polynomial once you have a root you can divide it out and then use Newton's method for the lower order polynomial, and repeat until you reach the trivial case. There are a lot of numerical subtleties in all this which I won't pretend I understand fully, but I'm guessing for your homework this would be plenty good enough. BTW also look into Horner's method for the evaluation of polynomials.

Comment: You have to search from multiple starting points. Make a loop and  try with multiple initial x. Or modify the function each time you find a root like Ian Bush suggests,

Comment: As mentioned above, loop with multiple starting values.  Note that this method can fail even when there are roots!. Add a counter = counter + 1 in this loop that you reset to zero for every initial guess. Give up on a guess with an exit command after about 20 iterations. (This method is very fast).

Comment: There are problems with this approach though. X must be an integer for the loop to work and it cannot be redefined inside the loop, so I'd have to modify the expression x-f/df somehow.

Comment: You can compute x from i, t is trivial, no problem at all.

Comment: Oh, you mean do something like x = x + i?  I tried that but there wouldn't be any convergence evaluation, the algorithm will essentially just analyze the value of df for many points and hope to hit a root, the whole essence of Newton's method is lost. If this isn't what you had in mind, please clarify.

Comment: @Insight That or just x = i*something.  But not to analyze `df` for great many points but to start the Newton-Raphson method from much fewer points! As the answer below says, Newton-Raphson is a **local** method. With different starting points you will get different root. The area of convergence to any given root may be very unpredictable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal

Answer (score 3):

A possible algorithm to find all roots of the polynomial P consists in:

- Start from some X0 and find a root R, using Newton's algorithm.
- Divide P by (X-R): the division is exact (up to numerical error) since R is a root. (this step is called *deflation*)
- Restart from the beginning if the quotient has degree > 1.

There are some subtleties:

- If your polynomial has real coefficients and X0 is real, you will only find a real root, if there is any. To find complex roots, you then have to start from a complex X0, and of course use complex arithmetic.
- Not all values of X0 will guarantee convergence, as Newton-Raphson is a *local* method. See [Newton-Kantorovitch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantorovich_theorem) and [basins of attraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Nonlinear_equation_or_system) of the Newton method.
- If there are multiple roots, convergence there is much slower. There are ways to adapt Newton's method to deal with this.
- Numerical errors introduced in the deflation step add up and usually leads to poor accuracy of the subsequent roots. This is especially a problem for polynomials of high degree (how much high really depends). In extreme cases, the computed roots can be quite far from the exact roots. Furthermore, some polynomials are more "difficult" than others: see for instance [Wilkinson's polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial).
- There are ways to find information on the roots (bound on the absolute values, circles enclosing the roots...), this can help to pick a good X0 in the algorithm: see [Geometrical properties of polynomial roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots). If you are only looking for real roots of a real polynomials, you first find bounds, then use [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) to find intervals enclosing the roots. Another approach in the real case is to first find the roots of the derivative P' (and to find its roots, first find roots of P'', etc.), as the roots of P' separate the roots of P (except for multiple roots).
- Another suggested reading: [Roots of polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Roots_of_polynomials). Note that there are much better algorithms than Newton+deflation. There are also algorithms designed to find all the roots.

However, if you are only interested in this specific polynomial, I suggest to first have a look at the problem, as it's much easier than the general case: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4-26x%5E3%2B131x%5E2-226x%2B120).
Here, starting with integer values of X0 is going to work quite well...

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I give you below what I think is a better Newton-Raphson code, using Fortran-90 function declaration and a "while" rather than a blind "do".  Best, Fabio M. S. Lima

```
PROGRAM Newton2
! Newton-Raphson method in Fortran-90
implicit none
integer i,imax
real x,xnew,tol
parameter (imax = 30)
parameter (tol = 0.00001)

print*, '*** Initial value: '
read*,x
xnew = 0.5 !Just to begin the loop below
i=0
do while ((abs(xnew-x)>tol) .and. (i<imax))
  i=i+1       
  x = xnew
  xnew = x -f(x)/f1(x)
  print*, i,xnew,f(xnew)
end do
if (i>imax-2) then
  print*,'# Error: Newton-Raphson has not converged after ',i,' iterations!'
  else
    print*,'* After ',i,' iterations, we found a root at ',xnew
endif

contains

function f(z)
real z,f

f = z**4 -26.0*(z**3) +131.0*(z**2) -226.0*z +120.0

end function f

function f1(z)
real z,f1

f1 = 4.0*(z**3) -3.0*26.0*(z**2) +2.0*131.0*z -226.0

end function f1

END PROGRAM Newton2
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem Insight asked about? (Finding multiple roots)

Comment: For finding all real roots of a given polynomial equation, I would taken into account the simple method described in a recent paper, at https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.00372#:~:text=Newton's%20method%20for%20polynomial%20root,only%20guaranteed%20to%20converge%20locally.